# Setting at the same time: focus to carousel and change of item

Tags: javascript, html, widget, carousel

I am using a carousel widget of the hugo framework but this is might be a very basic html question. I want a hyperlink in the text to do two things: change the item of the carousel widget and to focus on it.

My current code looks like the following:

```
<a href="#hero_carousel" data-target="#hero_carousel" data-slide-to="2">linked phrase</a>
```

This now successfully changes the item of the carousel to the desired one. But it does not focus to the carousel.

On the other hand I can focus on the carousel like this but of course the item of the carousel is not changed:

```
<a href="#hero_carousel">linked phrase</a>
```

So how can I combine both? I tried also to include the data-target and data-slide attributes into a li-tag that surrounds the a-tag, which indeed triggers the change of item but which also ignores the href.

I also tried a span-tag within the a-tag without success either.

Maybe I need to do something with javascript? I tried but don't know javascript very well.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

OK, after all I solved the issue like the following. I created a javascript that scrolls to the carousel. I actually also built a button to connect that javascript. And within a table, I created cells that contain the attributes data-slide-to.

```
<th data-target="#hero_carousel" data-slide-to="4">
<button type="button" style="width:100%" onclick="document.getElementById('screen_focus').scrollIntoView({
  behavior: 'smooth'});">Daten sammeln</button></th>
```